# Adding Three20 to existing project in Xcode 4.5.1

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5, three20

I am trying to add Three20 in my project. I referred their [article](http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-Adding-Three20-To-Your-Project) and tried both their ways to add it, but have got no success. Is there any trick/step I am missing? Has anyone else faced a similar problem?

Comment: this should work
https://github.com/facebook/three20/wiki/Adding-Three20-to-a-Project

Comment: There's no sample code or details of what you've done, so I have to ask. Did you add the Three20 framework in "Link Binary With Libraries"?

Comment: As you didn't integrate Three20 yet: I would suggest not to add it and to search for alternatives, as Three20 seems to be no longer maintained/updated.

Comment: Three20 is awful. It may have had some relevance in the early days but you'd need a really good reason for adding it to a project today.

Comment: Hello Guys, I read allover that adding Three20 should be avoided or an alternative should be found, but the thing is that I have taken some one else's existing project and the only way it runs is with Three20, so have no other option.

Comment: did you try the python script thingi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully add the three20 to existing project in Xcode 4.5.2.

[This doc](https://github.com/facebook/three20) should work

Another method is the using ttmodule.py that provided by the three20,document is [here](http://three20.info/article/2011-03-10-Xcode4-Support).